# show custom exceptions in kohana 3.3 template controller

Tags: php, templates, controller, kohana, hmvc

I wish to show custom exception pages in my application. In documentation is written:
"Note: We can also use HMVC to issue a sub-request to another page rather than generating the Response in the HTTP_Exception itself." The problem is i don't know how to do it.
Code which I am using is:

```
class HTTP_Exception_404 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404 {

    /**
     * Generate a Response for the 404 Exception.
     *
     * The user should be shown a nice 404 page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function get_response()
    {
        $view = View::factory('errors/404');

        // Remembering that `$this` is an instance of HTTP_Exception_404
        $view->message = $this->getMessage();

        $response = Response::factory()
            ->status(404)
            ->body($view->render());

        return $response;
    }
}
```

It is working but i need to show the message in currently used template.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to bother with sub-requests if all you want is to use the template.  Here's the easy way:

```
class HTTP_Exception_404 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404 {

    public function get_response()
    {
        $view = View::factory('errors/404');

        // Remembering that `$this` is an instance of HTTP_Exception_404
        $view->message = $this->getMessage();

        // Wrap it in our layout
        $layout = $layout = View::factory('template');
        $layout->body = $view->render();

        $response = Response::factory()
            ->status(404)
            ->body($layout->render());

        return $response;
    }
}
```

If you really must use a sub-request, just do the sub-request normally:

```
class HTTP_Exception_404 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404 {

    public function get_response()
    {
        $request = Request::factory('route_to_error_page_action')
            ->method(Request::POST)
            ->post(array('message' => $this->getMessage()));
        $response = $request->execute();

        // If you didn't return the 404 code from the sub-request, uncomment this:
        $response->status(404);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: @masteryoda which of the two ways did you end up using?

Comment: The second - with subrequest. Because i have error controller working already. So Your code worked out of the box. Thanks again.